How to enable Undo/Redo in Eclipse
In Eclipse IDE, the Undo and Redo actions are disabled (greyed out in menu and toolbar, shortcuts ctrl-z, shift-ctrl-z don't work). My Eclipse version is 2023-09 (4.29.0).
I noticed that the actions had stopped working when I was editing a Python file (using PyDev, but I doubt that this was specific to this setup - at least this similar post encountered a very similar situation for a different setup).
If there was a specific trigger for the problem, I didn't notice... Neither restarting Eclipse, nor restarting the computer, did work (as suggested here)
This is basically an update of this question, which is so old, that it may seem out of date. It is not, though.

Is there anything to undo in the selected editor? They are only enabled when you have made some change to the text in the selected editor.

Yes. No redo/undo whatsoever

Did you install any new plugin? What specific editor are you using (i.e. for which language, provided by which plugin)? Is it the same for all editors, views with text-inputs, etc.?

I just "solved" it, resp. it is working again. I changed Preferences→General→Editors→Text Editors→Undo history size from 200 to 0 and then to 1000. Now everything seems to be fine again.

@tobias_k No, I did not install anything new. When this thing happened, I was editing a Python file (with PyDev installed). I didn't test other file types before I fixed it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to reproduce the bug to answer that question...

Here is the fix, that worked in my case:
Go to  Preferences→General→Editors→Text Editors. Change history size. Re-start Eclipse.
(I changed it from 200 to 0 and then to 1000, but maybe it would have been already enough to touch it once)

Update: the problem re-appeared and the procedure "fixed" it (changing the value only once).

After altering the size, at first it seemed not to work, but then I closed and reopened the file and undo worked.
